# Best way to typecheck key or value in 'foreach' construct?

Tags: php

I'd like to typecheck the key (if a hash) and value of an array expression that's iterated over in a `foreach` construct, something like:

```
foreach ($reasons as AuthenticationResponse $reason)
...
```

Is there any alternative to doing this as an `instanceof` check in the loop body?

Comment: I think you are talking about the same thing as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12409915/231316). Short answer: no. Longer answer: you can type-hint to the IDE.

Comment: The language doesn't support it. Depending on how important it is for you, your options range from using docblock annotations (supported by many IDEs and static analysis tools) and getting a custom [collection](https://packagist.org/packages/vistik/typed-collections) implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but this is just one line of code and should not be any problem.

```php
class Test {
    public int $number;
}

class Dummy {
    public int $number;
}

$tests = [];

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $test = new Test();
    $test->number = $i;
    $dummy = new Dummy();
    $dummy->number = $i;
    $tests[] = $test;
    $tests[] = $dummy;
}

foreach($tests as $test) {
    if(!$test instanceof Test) continue;
    echo get_class($test), $test->number, PHP_EOL;
}
```

This will skip all non Tests and output:

```
Test0
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test4
Test5
Test6
Test7
Test8
Test9
```

Comment: `continue` is clever!

Comment: @calligraphic-io I am doing that always. That prevents nesting.